# Java: Can this be done in one line? Return if Optional.isPresent() otherwise continue method

Tags: java

This is a trivial problem, but I'm curious if it can be done to clean up some code. Can the following be written in one line without generating an extra variable or calling the 'checkValue' method again? I have access up to java 17.

```
public Optional<String> someMethod() {
    // stuff here
    Optional<String> error = checkValue(someValue);
    if (error.isPresent()) return error;
    // otherwise continue this method
    // more stuff here
    return someOtherMethod();
}
```

I know it can be done if I call the checkValue method again, but imagine that this method has some heavy logic in it that we don't want to repeat.

Comment: `return checkValue(someValue).or(this::someOtherMethod);` (assuming `someOtherMethod` is not static

Comment: I don't think the answer cited as a duplicate is correct.  In each example, some form of `orElseGet` is used which does not return an `Optional`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Optional#or`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#or(java.util.function.Supplier)).

> returns an Optional describing the value of this Optional, if a value is present, otherwise an Optional produced by the supplying function.

```java
return checkValue(someValue).or(() -> {
    // other code...
    return someOtherMethod();
});
```

If there is only one method to run in the case where the first method returned an empty optional, then a method reference can be used.

```js
return checkValue(someValue).or(this::someOtherMethod);
// assuming someOtherMethod is an instance method
```

Comment: Or even shorter as one -liner using a method reference: ```return checkValue(someValue).or(this::someOtherMethod);```

Comment: @LuCio True, I had assumed that `// more stuff here` in the original question might've represented some other code.

Comment: I was focused on the "one line". But you're right.

Comment: This is solid, thank you. To add an additional caveat, which I think some of other commenters picked up here - what if I need to run something like checkValue many times? Or various other lines of code before the end of someMethod? With this strategy, seems like I would have to keep nesting it deeper and deeper. Is there a way to simply return to the current method without calling something else?

Comment: @user17331277 There's no way to return a value from a function without explicitly using a `return` statement (exceptions can stop the execution, but that's not useful here). So syntactically, there isn't much more that can be done here. You'll have to decide between this solution and what you originally had in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Using [@user16320675's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16320675/user16320675) comment, here is how it works.

- the first example is when there is no error. If the check determines validity, the  non-errored optional is returned.
- the second is when the is an error (in this case, an empty optional).  Then the other method is called via the `or` and that `Optional` is returned.

```
someValue = "Success!";
Optional<String> result =  checkValue(someValue).or(this::someOtherMethod);
System.out.println(result.get());

someValue = "";
result = checkValue(someValue).or(this::someOtherMethod);
System.out.println(result.get());
```

prints

```
Success!
Error encountered!
```

The supporting methods

```
public Optional<String> checkValue(String value) {
    if (value.isEmpty()) {
        return Optional.empty();
    }
    return Optional.of(value);
}

public Optional<String> someOtherMethod() {
    return Optional.of("Error encountered!");
}
```